# Get the model ID when updating a resource

Tags: laravel

I have a form that will submit a Patch request to the controller's update method.
But the update method requires to have $id, as you can see below whenever I try that I get a 
`No query results for model [Item].` Since the update method did not receive the $id of the model

```
public function update($id)
    {
        $item = Item::findOrFail($id);
        $update = Input::all();
            // some codes to save changes

        return Redirect::route('items.index');
    }
```

Another thing is that whenever I submit the form, url turns into something like this:

mw.dev/items/%7Bitems%7D

---

**Edit**

**routes.php**

```
Route::resource('items','ItemsController');
```

**ItemController**

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $item = Item::findOrFail($id);
        return View::make('items.edit')->with('item',$item);
    }
```

I have included the code on my **edit.blade.php**

```
{{Form::open(array('route' => 'items.update', 'method'=>'patch'))}}
    {{Form::text('barcode', $item->barcode, array('placeholder' => 'barcode'))}}
    {{Form::text('imei',$item->imei, array('placeholder' => 'imei'))}}
    {{Form::text('item_name', $item->item_name, array('placeholder' => 'item name'))}}
    {{Form::submit('edit')}}
{{Form::close()}}
```

Comment: How do you generate the route in the form ?

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha I have made an update to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the model to your view and need to pass the `id` parameter when generating the form. Assume that you have a `User` model and it's available in the view. So you may generate the form action using something like this:

```
// Using Form::open method with route
Form::open(array('route' => array('route.name', $user->id)))

// Using Form::model method with route
Form::model($user, array('route' => array('route.name', $user->id), 'method' => 'patch'))

// Using Form::open method with action
Form::open(array('action' => array('Controller@update', $user->id), 'method' => 'patch'))

// Using Form::open method with url
Form::open(array('url' => 'something/update/' . $user->id, 'method' => 'patch'))
```

Check more on [Opening A Form](http://laravel.com/docs/html#opening-a-form).

Answer (score 0):

The URL

```
mw.dev/items/%7Bitems%7D
```

is most likely the url-encoded form of

```
mw.dev/items/{items}
```

I suppose there is a problem in the form submission or in the `<form>`'s `action` paremeter or in the `Route::*` declaration in `routes.php`.

This could also explain why you don't get any `$id` upon submission.